# Sticky footer with WordPress Twenty Twelve

Tags: wordpress, footer, sticky

I'm trying to get the footer of [my website](http://cresun.is-great.net) to stick to the bottom of a page. I've done some inspection with Firebug and found that the footer is currently being wrapped along with the rest of the site content.

My theory at this point is that the footer should stick to the bottom of a page, if the component that defines the height of a page is set to 100%, leaving the footer underneath this element.

Would appreciate if anyone could inspect the code and give me some instructions of what to edit, as I have absolutely no idea where to continue from here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sticky footer code example from [here](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html) you will need to start by reorganizing the layout of your page.

The code on your site is:

```
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <header id="masthead">Header code</header>
    <div id="main">page body code</div>
    <footer id="colophon">footer code</footer>
</div>
```

In order to get the sticky footer to work using the example link that I sent, you would need to restructure your website code using something like this (notice the footer is outside the DIV):

```
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <header id="masthead">Header code</header>
    <div id="main">page body code</div>
</div>
<footer id="colophon">footer code</footer>
```

The CSS code accompanied by this would look something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body {height: 100%;}

#page {min-height: 100%;}

#main {overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 150px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */

#colophon {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;} 

/*Opera Fix*/
body:before {
    content:"";
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:0;
    margin-top:-32767px;/
}
</style>
```

I have used the sticky footer before which works great but I have not used it in WordPress website so you will have to play around with it. It might be a challenge to reorganize the main HTML WordPress elements but hopefully this will get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add/amend the #footer within your .css as this needs to be set as position:fixed; in order to 'stick' this to the bottom, it would be worth adding margin-bottom:0px; or bottom:0px; so that this touches the very bottom of your page and also set the width to width:100%; ... if you can check your .css for #footer, or add this as below just too see what happens, then we can play about from there..

```
#footer {position:fixed; margin-bottom:0px; width:100%;}
```

you should also really add height:***px; depending on how 'high' the footer needs to be, you can play about with this until this line meets the top of your footer so that when you scroll up and down, your page text meets this line perfectly